# VBA Macro to append columns data to the last row

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am very new to VBA and trying to consolidate an excel file with 0.2 million rows.

My excel format is

[image]

You can see that so much duplicated data there. I want to make the whole sheet have only 4 columns by appending other columns data as the headers are same.

For example :

```
Data in the columns  F2-I2 will go to A4 - D4 

                     F3 - I3 will go to A5 - D5

similarly

                     K2 - N2 will go to A6 - D6

                     K3 - N3 will go to A7 - D7
```

And follows

I want to write a VBA macro and by running the macro it should make the excel have only 4 columns by appending all other columns data.

Can someone please help me achieving that.

**NOTE** : After doing that my excel will have around 1 million rows. So i am looking for a solution with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this only can be solved by looping through the blocks, the columns and the rows which probably takes some time if you have a million values.

To increase performance disable screenUpdating and to ensure that the macro does not crash include DoEvents() in the loop.

Please note that the maximum number of rows in Excel is 1'048'576

```
Sub moveValues()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim lastRowTarget As Long
Dim lastRowSource As Long

Dim wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 6 To 16 Step 5
    lastRowSource = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, Chr(64 + i)).End(xlUp).row
    lastRowTarget = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    col = 1
    For j = i To i + 3
        For k = 2 To lastRowSource
            wks.Cells(lastRowTarget + k - 1, col) = wks.Cells(k, j)
            DoEvents
        Next k
        col = col + 1
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```